# Displaying a post containing a form in front of the blog list

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

Is there anyway you can display a post containing a form in front of the blog list? We can certainly display the excerpt and show it in the blog list. I am having hard time displaying a post containing a form. I wanted to display the form in front http://clip2net.com/s/iPD8ns rather than clicking and go to the individual post http://clip2net.com/s/iPDapj.

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can install some plugin,
Like this:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/
When install and create a form, you can used plugin shortcode in your posts and display wath you need.